# Why the Insert command delete old rows in the database

Tags: sql-server, insert, command

I'm trying to add a row in the database by using the `insert` command.

It successfully adds the row, but the old rows in the database were deleted after executing the command!

```
Dim connetionString As String
        Dim cnn As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim sql As String
        connetionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Datab1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"


        sql = "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('e', 'e')"    


        cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, cnn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()    

            cmd.Dispose()
            cnn.Close()
            MsgBox(" ExecuteNonQuery in SqlCommand executed !!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Aren't you looking at the wrong database? Your connection string attaches Datab1.mdf, perhaps this is not db you are checking after the insert?

Answer (score 1):

Find the trigger created on this table which is causing to delete the old rows.

[image]

If you want to quickly list down the tables having triggers in your database, here's how to do so:

```
USE [YourDB]

SELECT

OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) AS TableName,

name AS TriggerName,

create_date AS CreationDate,

modify_date AS ModifyDate

FROM sys.triggers
```

Comment: Man what u mean .. I can not understand u

Comment: There may be a possibility of existing trigger on this table and this trigger is getting fired automatically when you executes insert statement from .net code. So execute the query given in my post and check whether any trigger is created or not.

Comment: did you find the culprit trigger. Feel free to ask if you have still issues.

Comment: Mr.Romil Am work weth vb.net so I did not fined any trigger in the database and no stored procedures write it ..

Comment: Attach Datab1.mdf in sqlexpress and then check for trigger. One more thing you can try, create a clone of Table1 using "Select * into table2 from table1". Now execute your code on table2, you will have no issues.